# How to make a search query in Firestore Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, google-cloud-firestore

Im working my first Firebase app [Objective - C] and I want to know the fastest way to implement a search for a field, I've been reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), and I found:

I make a reference to the document:

```
 FIRQuery *capitalCities =
        [[self.db collectionWithPath:@"cities"] queryWhereField:@"capital" isEqualTo:@YES];
```

Then they show how to make the search query:

```
[citiesRef queryWhereField:@"name" isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:@"San Francisco"];
```

Thats what I dont get, I implemented that code, and If I send:

```
[citiesRef queryWhereField:@"name" isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:@"Kar"];
```

What I get is (descending order):

```
2017-10-12 18:53:36.138[2697:663963] SearchREsult: {
    nombre = "victoria ";
}
2017-10-12 18:53:36.138[2697:663963] SearchREsult: {
    nombre = karlo;
}
2017-10-12 18:53:36.138[2697:663963] SearchREsult: {
    nombre = "karla ";
}
2017-10-12 18:53:36.139[2697:663963] SearchREsult: {
    nombre = "V\U00edctor";
}
2017-10-12 18:53:36.142[2697:663963] SearchREsult: {
    nombre = "Ra\U00fal";
}
2017-10-12 18:53:36.143[2697:663963] SearchREsult: {
    nombre = "Ra\U00fal";
}
2017-10-12 18:53:36.144[2697:663963] SearchREsult: {
 nombre = Pepe;
}
2017-10-12 18:53:36.145[2697:663963] SearchREsult: {
    nombre = "Mar\U00eda";
}
```

So the second and third results are correct, but I get more "trash" results I dont need.

So my question is how `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and `isLessThanOrEqualTo` Firestore methods works with strings, such as "San Fransisco" documentation example, so I know if I can achieve a simple search query with some API method or I will have to implement the [Solution Alternatives](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) that Google provides for more complicated searches.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get a range of results. In that case you need both `and`. So:

```
[[citiesRef queryWhereField:@"name" isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:@"Kar"]
            queryWhereField:@"name" isLessThan:@"Kas"]
```

This will give you all documents where `name` starts with `Kar`.

Comment: But in that case, I must come with a method to manage this query if Im getting the search from a searchbar, I must come with whis manually? (For example read the last letter from the search string and find the next letter in the alphabet)

Comment: Ah... a common trick is to to the less than with a suffix of one of the last characters in unicode, e.g. `"Kar\uf8ff"`. See for an example this documentation page for the Firebase Realtime Database, where you'd use the same trick: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries

Comment: Sorry but im still dont get it, what would be the equivalent from the 
 firebase example in objective-c? `[[usersReference queryWhereField:@"nombre" isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:stringToSearch] queryWhereField:@"nombre" isLessThan:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\uf8ff", stringToSearch]];`